# Identifying a movie about a children's summer camp

Tags: identify-this-movie

When I was younger, I saw a movie, but never caught the name of it. Unfortunately, I don't recall too much.
I watched it no later than 1999, and I estimate it's origin to be from the 80's or 90's and was most probably an American movie.

Below is a list of things I know with some certainty:

• In the movie, they seemed to be at a summer camp with a lake.

• From what I recall, boys and girls were separated into their own camp or cabin.

• The boys and girls seemed to be at 'war' with each other or at least hated each other, but our main character (a shy boy?) was in love with one of the girls.

• The only scene I can recall is where the main character has written some poetry or a love letter on a piece of paper and was about to send it to one of the girls:

The other boys somehow find out what he's doing, and ask what's on piece of paper. Not wanting to expose himself as a 'girl-sympathiser', he lies and tells them it's a letter full of insults. They ask to see and to stop them finding out the truth, he reads it out loud, ad-libbing it.

One of the boys then takes it to wherever the girls are staying, but the boy, mere feet from the house/cabin/whatever sneezes into the paper, making it illegible. I believe two girls are on a balcony, and he assures the girls that it doesn't matter that he's ruined the letter, as he can recall it word for word, to which he tells them all the nasty things that the boy ad-libbed.

That's all I can remember. Any idea what this might have been?

Comment: Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [**Identify-This-X Questions**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it this movie?
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110366/

The Little Rascals (1994) 
Quote from the summary of the film

> Alfalfa is wooing Darla and his "He-Man-Woman-Hating" friends attempt
>   to sabotage the relationship.

Another quote from the plot summary

> The boys catch Alfalfa in the company of Darla -- "a girl!" Alfalfa isn't like his friends because he's in love with Darla, and unfortunately threatens the very existence of their "boys only" club. The club's members try their hardest to break the two apart, eventually causing their beloved clubhouse to burn down. Darla is mistakenly led to believe Alfalfa feels ashamed of her, so she turns her attentions to Waldo,

And I believe this is the scene you mentioned
[Love letter to Darla](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2ONM6n7avA)

Comment: Wow. This is most definitely the same movie. I imagined it so different in my head, but there's no denying that this is it. Thank you.